# Convert PPT into Images in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, powerpoint, docsplit

I am using docsplit gem to convert PPT into images

```
Docsplit.extract_images(uploaded.path.to_s, :size => '550x', :format => [:jpg],:output=>"#{Rails.root}/public/images")
```

it convert successfully but i will take more time . Can i Convert any other way Please anyone help me.

Comment: I am also using docsplit to extract thumbnail for the documents being uploaded, but i am getting an error **Docsplit OfficeNotFound** i have not installed libre office into my mac, if this is causing error or what else.

Answer (score 3):

Im using `Docsplit` as well,
and if you meant that your application is idling/loading while docsplit is converting you ppt files you should keep in mind that:

Every process that takes time, will get you application "stuck" until its job is done.

therefore,
You should run heavy job/tasks that takes a long time - in the background / in delayed job

If you do so: users won't get stuck!

(dont forget that you should let them know that the job is "in process", so they won't think there was an error)